# how to add custom weight set in woo commerce in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I've WordPress Woo commerce websites. I've three variable product attributes like a 250g,500g and 1kg.When I checkout it will generate me a message that you're selected attribute greater 250g. How can I do this ?any one guide me  it will possible plugin or custom code where i change.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding Shipping Dimensions to Products
Measurement Settings
Many of our API based Shipping Methods require that your products have dimensions and weights set. Before adding weights and dimensions you should first configure the units and ensure they are enabled:

> To choose the unit of measurement for your weight and dimensions, go
>   to WooCommerce > Settings > Products

Enter all values in decimal form, without special characters (e.g., 12 or 12.5). All fields must be set.

[For more details click here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-dimensions-and-weights-to-products-for-shipping/)